# How to make excel combobox.value triggering other textbox from access database

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

i have a combobox that have values from access database, **how can i make the combobox as a trigger**. When a value was chosen, then other textbox is automatically filled with corresponding value from access database? Thanks

```
On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
         "Data Source=E:\Database.accdb"
rs.Open "specification", cn, adOpenStatic
rs.MoveFirst
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rs![SerialNoCubicle]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With


rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Exit Sub
```

this code for calling the values from database displayed in combobox

---

### UPDATE

i found the solution but my code is pretty noob, need someone to help me simplify the code if it is possible

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
Dim sql1 As String
Dim sql2 As String
Dim sql3 As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=E:\Database.accdb"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

sql1 = "Select * FROM specification Where SerialNoCubicle = '8'"
sql2 = "Select * FROM specification Where SerialNoCubicle = '17'"
sql3 = "Select * FROM specification Where SerialNoCubicle = '18'"

    If TextBox8.Value = 8 Then
        rs.Open sql1, cn
    With rs
        TextBox1.Value = rs.Fields("Project").Value
        TextBox2.Value = rs.Fields("ProjectNo").Value
        TextBox3.Value = rs.Fields("No&DateofDrw").Value
        TextBox4.Value = rs.Fields("DrawingNumber").Value
        TextBox5.Value = rs.Fields("NameofCubicle").Value
        TextBox6.Value = rs.Fields("SingleLineLayout").Value
        TextBox7.Value = rs.Fields("PlantofTest").Value
        TextBox9.Value = rs.Fields("TypeofProduct").Value
        TextBox10.Value = rs.Fields("IPofProduct").Value
        TextBox11.Value = rs.Fields("Substation").Value
    End With
    End If

    If TextBox8.Value = 17 Then
        rs.Open sql2, cn
    With rs
        TextBox1.Value = rs.Fields("Project").Value
        TextBox2.Value = rs.Fields("ProjectNo").Value
        TextBox3.Value = rs.Fields("No&DateofDrw").Value
        TextBox4.Value = rs.Fields("DrawingNumber").Value
        TextBox5.Value = rs.Fields("NameofCubicle").Value
        TextBox6.Value = rs.Fields("SingleLineLayout").Value
        TextBox7.Value = rs.Fields("PlantofTest").Value
        TextBox9.Value = rs.Fields("TypeofProduct").Value
        TextBox10.Value = rs.Fields("IPofProduct").Value
        TextBox11.Value = rs.Fields("Substation").Value
    End With
    End If

    If TextBox8.Value = 18 Then
        rs.Open sql3, cn
    With rs
        TextBox1.Value = rs.Fields("Project").Value
        TextBox2.Value = rs.Fields("ProjectNo").Value
        TextBox3.Value = rs.Fields("No&DateofDrw").Value
        TextBox4.Value = rs.Fields("DrawingNumber").Value
        TextBox5.Value = rs.Fields("NameofCubicle").Value
        TextBox6.Value = rs.Fields("SingleLineLayout").Value
        TextBox7.Value = rs.Fields("PlantofTest").Value
        TextBox9.Value = rs.Fields("TypeofProduct").Value
        TextBox10.Value = rs.Fields("IPofProduct").Value
        TextBox11.Value = rs.Fields("Substation").Value
    End With
    End If

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `_change` event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    'or create your own query
    qry = "SELECT [FIELD1] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [FIELD2] = " & Me.ComboBox1.value & ";"

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
     "Data Source=E:\Database.accdb"

    rs.open qry, cn
    Me.Textbox1.Value = rs![FIELD1]

    'rinse and repeat for other text boxes

    rs.close
    cn.close

End Sub
```

Comment: i got an error in "rs.open qry, cn, adOpenStatic" -data type mismatch in criteria expression-